# Issues with NordVPN on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, vpn, nordvpn

I'm using NordVPN version 3.12 on an Ubuntu 18.04.6 media server and I've run into many connection issues. The Linux CLI version is very unstable compared to the desktop version, with the VPN getting stuck in a reconnecting loop. When trying to reconnect, it will run a loading animation until I quit the SSH session and rejoin the server.

After SSHing back into the server, the VPN status will be displayed as "Reconnecting". Trying to run `systemctl restart nordvpn.service | systemctl restart nordvpnd.service` will restart the service but Nord will still get stuck in a connection loop. Trying to use `kill -9 [ID]` will stop the service but after restarting the service it will throw this error: `Whoops! Cannot reach System Daemon.` when running `nordvpn connect`. The only reliable way I've found to get the VPN started again is to restart the system. It seems these issues start after a few days of letting the system run on the VPN connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up ditching the NordVPN cli client and going with Openpyn. It's an open-source Python script for OpenVPN and some Nord API services. Link to the project: https://github.com/jotyGill/openpyn-nordvpn

Command used: `sudo openpyn ca -f -d -r -t 10 --allow [Ports to Allow] --silent --p2p`

While not perfect, in the event that a server disconnects, it will automatically try to find another server to connect to. I've had Openpyn running in daemon mode for a few days now and the connection still works.